# What led to this question not being well received?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, etiquette

My most recent post on SO was poorly received and led to some back and forth in comments which is where this question comes from. I am curious which factors led to this post not being well received so I may post higher quality content in the future.

Some of the responses to my post which indicate it was not well received:

1. Offense at calling something in java "broken"
2. That my post doesn't meet SO guidelines
3. The post is not constructive.

My thoughts in response thus far can be classified as:

1. Explaining a person doesn't understand the problem
2. Explaining that I've already provided a test to run
3. Wondering when anyone will understand the issue and want to discuss it instead of discussing how terrible and inflammatory I am because I labeled something in java as "broken".

Also, the back and forth in the comments tried my patience and I feel they could have been more constructive.

Please let me know the proper way to respond in comments when a post is not being well received, and how I could have improved my post so it was better received.

Here's the offending post:
[Is this the only workaround for dispersed schema hierarchy validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091883/is-java-schema-validation-broken/28152932)

Comment: @lexicore Have at the roast

Comment: Fair warning, you do know you just invoked the meta effect on yourself, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what that means, but I'm certainly positive I will receive quite a bit of negative responses directed at me. I'm hoping to extract some useful tidbits in carrying forth the original topic at hand. At the core of it, I just want to make java better, and I'm willing to take all the criticism from a large community if that means I can fix something. Believe it or not, I care about java, and I want the simple things to be simple.

Comment: Hmm I dunno, looks like you are knowledgeable and asked a good Q . But yea... avoid rhetotric about politics etc

Comment: *"Explaining that the person doesn't understand the problem"* Rather than doing that, i'd suggest just not responding to said person. All telling the person that does is inflame, it won't help the situation. Don't engage.

Comment: It started bad, and you edited into a better question. Is it really surprising that the first version was poorly received ?

Comment: I downvoted this post because it frames the quesion in terms of personality rather than behavior or other content.

Comment: SO voitng is largely about personality.

Comment: @PhilLello Can you back that statement up, or perhaps clarify it? SO voting is about *quality* in my experience.

Comment: You have one upvote now... seems you're Ok !  Sometimes people glaze  over walls-of-code tho

Comment: Just to be clear, in that initial post I was *told* to create a meta question asking about this. I now see *this* question has many downvotes. I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. I am doing what I was told. How do I now fix my meta question? Is there a meta-meta-SO? Joking aside, seriously what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Russ - Re: Meta post. Meta (much like SO) is here to help future users. While examining specific scenarios can be important when a user comes across them in the future, how would they find this one? It doesn't exactly lend itself to being easily searchable, and it is a narrow case as opposed to a broader situation. If this had been more generalized and less of a personal review it would have been received better. Also, again with the titles (sorry to harp on you with this), but this title kind of invites people to downvote. It doesn't seem very constructive at first.

Comment: So I'm really stuck between a rock and a hard place here. I was instructed to create this by another person on the linked post (see lexicore's response). If this is supposed to be generic and searchable and reusable this is a terrible place to post something like this. I'm torn between whether to ask what to name *this* one or just deleting the darn thing entirely. So here goes, what should the title and theme of this question be to adhere to meta standards? Should I just remove this? This was very helpful to me but agree its not resusable. So now what do we do. Was this the meta effect joke?

Comment: Voting on Meta is more about agreeing/disagreeing with the subject of the post than about the quality of the post itself (although it can mean that as well). On Meta, we like to concentrate on content, not users. So we identify problems with a question's content and title, not with a user. So when you have a title asking why you are a terrible poster, that is not received well. If you'd like to change your title, that would go a long way toward resolution. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect for information on the meta effect.

Comment: So I have to be the dumbest person on the planet, but I'll ask the question I'm not learning to hate, what should the title of this post be, to follow guidelines? How about "What is wrong with the linked SO post?". Does that follow guidelines? If you mean change the title on the original post I already did to precisely what was recommended, but now I have 2 recommendations for the original post so not sure what to do there.

Comment: "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”" ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
...
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" I can't get any more specific, and I am asking an answerable question. The common theme SO users have of "this isn't a quick and easy to answer question so I can up my rep" so they label it "not adhering to the guidelines" to me shows a broken community. Just because the question can't be answered in 5 seconds to up your rep doesn't mean it isn't SO format.

Comment: @gant I will admit the part you stated is certainly relevant and I've already read it in the help after the help section was linked to me. While I personally think we as programmers are doing ourselves a disservice by "not talking about it" and I see value in raising visibility of issues in something we all need to use every day, i respect whats in the help article and have removed all "broken" terminology. The way the original article stands there is no "this is broken" it's "whats the best way to work around this". I wish more of the community cared about what was wrong and wanted to fix it.

Comment: my understanding is, primary purpose of this rule is to prevent 'false alarms". If it wasn't there, SO would be flooded with ["select is broken"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) complaints - and since moderators can't really reliably tell which of these are [genuine](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2011/11/03/38695/) and which are plain ignorant, there would be no way to correct this

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense to me and helps me understand why there might be some good in preventing it. SO makes it clear they don't want discussions. I know SO has many daughter sites. I'm wondering if there is a place for discussion questions where the part of my question regarding discussion could be had? I have to imagine there must be a lot of good discussions that can be had in development.

Answer (score 13):

Even if other people don't understand your problem, that in no way makes it appropriate for you to use inflammatory language, nor is there any problem with such a person informing you that your post is currently worded in an inflammatory tone.

That you've provided a solution has no bearing on whether or not the post meets SO's guidelines.  If it doesn't meet SO's guidelines then it doesn't meet SO's guidelines.  Either edit it until it does, or find somewhere other than SO to post it.

If you're wondering why people aren't participating in your flame bait, and instead telling you that you're posting flame bait and then ceasing to participate, it's because they are here to participate in constructive discussions, not flame wars.  You shouldn't be surprised that people are telling you to phrase your question more constructively, instead of participating in an unconstructive discussion.

Your meta question gives the impression that you know *exactly* what you're doing wrong, and you just don't care.  If that's the case, I don't know what exactly you're expecting us to tell you.  Don't do the things that you already know you're doing wrong.  Do you really need us to tell you that?

Comment: At some point, yes, it turned into a flame war - but only in the comments. The fact the original title and post welcomed angry responses did very much surprise me. Other than the guidelines that show when asking a new SO question, do you have a link to these guidelines? The only thing I'm aware of is the "make sure it's an answerable question, rather than a discussion" is there more?

Comment: I've also asked for ANY way to phrase it more constructively and said I was willing to change the title - and still am. The thing is, people got angry at the title and the way the question was worded, and that was the end of it. Snap judgments, and no one making suggestions to their issues. No one, not even now, has provided an alternative "less inflammatory" statement. Additionally, why is calling something in java broken "inflammatory"? Why do we (yes im a java guy) feel like we should not call something thats broken what it is?

Comment: @Russ There's a link to the help center on the top navigation bar of every single page.  If you were surprised that your wording was perceived as being unconstructive, why did you not address that problem when commentors informed you of that issue?

Comment: If you click on the "Help" dropdown at the top of every page, you can go to the help center which has tons of information about the Stack Overflow guidelines. Especially useful would be http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please see the edit to my above comment, I explained why I haven't changed any edits - no suggestions were given. I'm being told the title is "bad" and i ask for a modification, and no one has a suggestion. I'm a firm believer someone who cricizes without providing an alternative is just a whiner. I am *very happy* to change the title and even did change it once posing it as a question to try to make it softer because no one gave me an alternative. You'll notice that theme carries in my OP, I am trying to provide a better solution.

Comment: @Russ If you feel that the post is actually constructive, then why is your response to someone feeling that it's not constructive, "you just don't understand it" and "you should just answer it anyway".  Instead as *them* how they think it could be phrased better, or explain why you think that the post is constructively phrased.

Comment: If you're talking about kjhughes, it's because it was quite clear he didn't understand the problem after his first response was "use this solution" which failed miserably, i informed him, and then he said "create an MCVE" when there was already one there. I think that person spoke for themselves there. Like I said, we can talk about the comments all day long. I'll be the first to admit I got frustrated. My point is, no one - even still - has provided an alternative. Do you have one? What title would you like?

Comment: What are your thoughts on "Is this the only workaround for dispersed schema hierarchy validation?"

Comment: @Russ Just ask how to do whatever it is you want to do.  Commentary about your opinion of the language, framework, etc. is superfluous.  Ask how to import a schema that imports another schema (not sure if that's an accurate representation of your real question).  You can mention what you've done so far, what problems you have with it, what has prevented you from doing what you'd *like* to do, etc.  Don't commentate on things; just stick to the facts.  Say what you can't do, not why you think the language is terrible for not letting you do something.

Comment: So in that light would it be best to remove the description at the top? It's kind of a hard question to ask succinctly. Is the current title good in your opinion? Does the body contain info that shouldn't be there? I will make it better if I can get specific suggestions. Starting to wonder if it, and this post should just be deleted? Thoughts?

Comment: @Russ No, I would not go with "Is this workaround the only way to do X".  Rather ask, "How do I do X?" as the title.  In the body explain what you have already tried to do in order to do X, and explain what problems you have with those solutions.  Answerers can then provide ways to do X; the best of which will (hopefully) be voted up to the top.

Comment: Well that's kind of a tough spot for me. I already received the suggested title from another SO user and now you disagree with that. Since I can't please everyone I'm going to leave it the way it is. Asking an opinion gives many answers, I'm trying to appease the community and have made changes. I'm doing the best I can, and again, I really only care about the issue, because it affects everyone.

Answer (score 10):

The final version of your question is what should have been posted to begin with, and that is one of the main problems with this post - that it wasn't originally posted with proper attention. The other issue being the title.

Users are generally displeased with posts which state in large bold letters that a popular framework or language feature is broken without any support aside from a text wall.

Essentially it began as a bug post with no code or reproducible scenario.

Further, it is absolutely not the burden of answerers to reproduce scenarios manually based on descriptions. The issue with that is it wastes everyone's time when several answerers have to all spend time creating a demo from scratch; and also it means that all the demos will have some form of variance.

So, what about this post makes you a terrible poster? Well, no one is really saying you are a terrible poster.

The problems this post suffered from was that it contained vitriol and didn't give enough consideration to other people's time.

Comment: And really, pet peeve:  all the spellings of `Java` as `java`.  If you're going to post a giant question, and repeatedly refer to a language in the question, at least use the correct casing.  It just looks lazy.

Comment: While my original post didn't include an MCVE, it did include one prior to the comment asking for one. As for the comment about how this end result should be how it started, I agree with that, but honestly I didn't think I would need more. I figured other people would know what I was talking about and figured it had probably been beaten to death and I was the only idiot who hand't heard about it yet. Consideration for other people's time was the reason for not including tons of schemas from the get-go. Keep it simple was the mentality. So it's not that I didn't care, I showed it differently.

Comment: @Russ - So in its current state, I think your question is fine. But to the other points, sometimes intentions get mixed up on the internet. Without an example it was very hard to reproduce to others, because there can be nuance which affects situations like this. Users want to ensure that your situation was not affected by nuance and was an actual result of the framework somehow not working with a scenario. In this case, it is very important to give an exact working set that everyone can use to verify with, or to say "I have seen that before" to. Not including it is kind of saying "you do it".

Comment: That's fine, in the future I will err on the side of posting code. As I stated, it wasn't my intention. I'm not one of the posters who is a kid in college or just trying to get a bandaid solution to apply at work so it doesn't bother me any. Like I said, I started small to try not to inundate and in the initial post did say I can offer code up but just didn't want to spam. The post was already very large.

Comment: @Russ - In general, I think that large posts are understandable as long as they are made to be readable and follow a logical path of description and reproduction of some problem scenario.

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the posters who've tried to give an answer to the question. I have also flagged two of your comments on my question as not constructive.

I actually don't mind your rant, not at all. I know your pain, often I often have such cases and sometimes I bang my head against the table silently screaming "why on earth this stuff just refuses to work".

But I'm not here to educate you on the anger management. Here are my two cents on how (maybe) could have done it better.

You came with the premise that "it is broken". Some people probably got uneasy with the tone (not me by the way). It looked more like you were trying to make your point rather than asking for help to fix it. Friendlier tone would make people more eager to be willing to help you.

You've posted some code, this was not a bad start. Would've be good to have full exception stack traces. Sometime it is possible to figure out the problem from the stack trace.

Not everyone would want to invest time to create a project in order to reproduce the problem. A ready-to-clone project on GitHub would have better chances, I think.

Still, you might also be a victim on your own research. What you report looked very much like a bug report. But SO is not a bug tracker for Xerces. Assuming this is a bug - what would you want from us next? To fix the Xerces code? Not in scope. So I'm not sure which help you expected.

It may also very well be that you're facing a complex problem and it would take a lot of resources to investigate. For me presonally the problem was not so interesting that I'd want to invest much time is it. I also remember that what you claim to be broken actually worked for me. So the devil is probably somewhere in details. So my balance was: either its a bug, should be a bug report. Or too localized and requires thorough debugging, too effort-consuming and not so interesting. At the same time you were showing disturbing patterns in communication and it looked like you were more interested in making a point than in actual help. So the whole thing had a good smell to end up not very good. I had such cases here on SO.

Look at your proclaimed goals:

> I had 2 goals of this post: to point out java's schema validation is broken (the sample schemas and sample test class show that), and to provide a better way (my provided schema resolver class).

From my point of view, none of these goals actually fits SO.

Making a point that something is broken? Definitely not.

Providing a better way? You could have made it a Q&A-style question, asking a question and answering it right away, thus sharing your experience on the topic.

You also said you wanted to fix it. My point here is that you don't fix it by ranting on SO about the problem. You fix it by providing a good bug report to the vendor and (ideally) a patch to fix the code.

I think that if you'd route the energy of your rant into the fix, you've probably already had a patch by now.

I find it very good that you've asked for the feedback on meta. Don't mind the downvotes, it's just a sign of "we think you did it wrong there", also a part of the feedback. Try to reflect on the situation when you calm down, I hope you'll see one or another point worth considering next time. SO has its own format. If you're interested on results (I mean getting the answers you want, not the rep), it is good to know this format and flow with it. Otherwise you'll end up in frustration.

Best wishes and good luck next time.

Comment: Excellently put.

Comment: I have some lessons learned even from that miserable failure of a post. Secondly, I agree with most of what you have written here, but do disagree on a few points. Which I will detail below which will probably take multiple comments. The one that bothers me the most is people claiming this question is not "SO format". From the help article I was linked: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, *but if your question generally covers…* a specific programming problem, [...] and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: My question could not be any more specific, is certainly about programming, and is definitely answerable. I have learned that calling something broken falls into the "___ sucks am i right" category and removed it. While I wish this community saw value in raising visibility to issues (we junit for a reason don't we?) I will concede that this particular user base doesn't see a difference between raising visibility of an important issue and "____ sucks am i right?" and then by transitive law have to concede it's not in line with the help guidelines.

Comment: As far as you quoting me on my goals of the post, there were many. It was a complex issue and a complex topic. My goals were also complex and hard to nail down. Any of the following would have satisfied me: "Hey dummy you're doing it wrong, do it this way", "You noob, when you do x in the resolver, you're supposed to do y", "You're right, java schema validation is broken, and that's why everyone and their mom uses z". As you can see, I don't mind if people called me names so long as they provided solutions. What I got instead was a bunch of empty comments who couldn't look past the word broken

Comment: If you can put yourself in my shoes, it is hard to do a lot of research on your own and work for a long time to try to fix something and make it the way it should be so everyone else can benefit, and when trying to post about it all you receive are nasty comments from people who *clearly* don't understand the issue and post a solution that was the first one you tried. So your comment as to you saw "disturbing patterns in my responses", perhaps you can see why it becomes a little frustrating if you're in my shoes. You can probably see this because you were of the few not offended by "broken".

Comment: Lastly, and most to the technical point at hand, I do not agree that filing a xerces bug is the appropriate step here. Even if java uses a redistributed xerces under the hood, filing a bug with xerces doesn't mean java is going to get that update. I appreciate you informing me that was the relationship, but I just don't agree on the "suggested fix". IMO if that is the relationship, it would take both a bug fix in xerces *and* I'd have to somehow get java to understand there was an issue, and get them to pull the latest from xerces in their next java update. I find this unlikely and thus am sad

Comment: Ultimately, if I didn't have such poor english writing skills and could write things like Travis J (the guy who edited this meta post) I would have never ran into this problem. I apparently have a very aggressive "ranty" way of writing and while I think being straight to-the-point adds value, it's clear to me now that not only does it not add value, it detracts value from the original post. So I think the big take away is study up on how to write in a neutral tone so I stop offending people which will allow them to focus on the issue instead of how much they hate my writing style.

Comment: Just a heads up on why it worked for you in the past - it's because your schema hierarchy did not have a dispersed organization (some schemas in one dir, some in others) and hence none of your imports had ../ or ./ in them. If that helps you in your coding in the future that'd be great. If you ever encounter a situation like that, come back to the original post and the resolver I posted will likely help, unless you run into the candy.xsd scenario. If you run into the candy scenario at least you know someone that keep you company in misery :)

Comment: @Russ You'll have to excuse me, I am afraid I am out of resources for further discussions on this topic. If you're interesed, [these are the schemas](http://schemas.opengis.net/) I work with.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that post merits a "horrible" designation (on the contrary, at the time of this meta post it sat at +1/-1 and was still open).

*Note: I am by no means a Java expert, so my answer is based on my impression of your post, not technical knowledge*.

**However**, you basically asked "Why doesn't Java work X way" or put another way, "Why doesn't Java support Y feature?"

We aren't the language designers for Java, so we don't know why it was designed a certain way, or why they chose a certain feature set. Thus, the question is basically unanswerable.

If you had simply asked "Can I improve this design", you would have done better, except that kind of question is better suited for Code Review than SO. Still, at least its answerable.

As a side note, SO probably isn't the place to "try and make Java better". Unless the developers of Java are actively reading all the Java questions to find unreported issues, it probably won't do anything. As the answer noted, you should file such issues with the relevant support team/forum.

Comment: In some aspects I agree with that comment you're referring to but also don't. The suggestion was to log the bug with the xerces project, however, I'm not convinced that will filter to java's internals. The main thing I was looking for was validation I was right in the statement of it being "broken". I could have very well gotten an answer of "no dummy do it this way" and I would have been very happy with that. Instead I found responses stating "hey dummy try this" and it was the first thing i tried and it failed miserably. A few people had known what I was talking about and provided validity.

Comment: @Russ Thats fine, but the way you phrased it was not an answerable question. Even asking "Is this the only workaround for X problem" would have been a much better way of asking.

Comment: I updated the title to "Is this the only workaround for dispersed schema hierarchy validation?" Is that a good title?

Comment: @Russ That seems like a good title to me. Note that the title is not necessarily the only problem. Avoid claiming that its "broken" in the body of the post as well (unless you have an actual, reproducible bug). Approach it like you are trying to solve a problem, not complain about an issue.

Comment: I will go remove it after I post this comment, but I do really want to try to understand this about our community. If something in java *is actually broken* why is it so bad to call it that? I code in java every day. I want java to be fast to write, easy to maintain, and in general make the simple things simple. Why is there so much anger over the word "broken"? What service are we providing ourselves by not using that term? Why is it a "four letter word"? If we pretend something isn't broken, how will it ever get fixed? The more people that know the better, no?

Comment: @Russ Forgive me if my explanation isn't very good here. Basically, saying something is "broken" just isn't very **constructive**. What does claiming the library doesn't work actually add to the post/discussion? Even if it is a real bug, we can't fix it. What really matters is how you dealt with the existing behavior. Basically, it makes it sound like you are complaining, and is a bunch of noise. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Russ lexicore's answer does a much better job explaining why saying something is "broken" isn't useful.